# Ftp craeting folder and setting permission with php

Tags: php, ftp, mkdir

I am making uploading site that creates folder for each user  to store his pics in , i tried to make the folder with the php normal function mkdir and setting the permissions to 0777 it's creating the folder but i cant add files from the php program only copying through windows explorer in the ftp server , but if i made the folder through ftp server and set the permissions manually it worked and uploaded pics , so i tried the ftp_mkdir with the following code :

```
$uploaddir="httpdocs/pics/".$uid.$uname;
if(!is_dir ($uploaddir))
{
    ftp_mkdir($conn, $uploaddir);
    ftp_chmod($conn,"0777", $uploaddir);

}
ftp_close($conn);
```

it's creating the folder but not with full permissions so you cant upload files to the folder until you set the permissions manually then it works fine

Comment: Why should you use the "ftp_" functions for this? You can use http://nl1.php.net/mkdir for this IF the writing permissions for the directory where you are creating dirs is correct. The PHP script tries to make a dir with no rights (nobody:nobody).